# How to convert Gregorian date to Coptic date in C#

Tags: c#, .net, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

How to convert Gregorian calendar to Coptic calendar in **C#**??

I have the following code:

```
public enum CopticMonth
{
    Thout = 1,
    Paopi = 2,
    Hathor = 3,
    Koiak = 4,
    Tobi = 5,
    Meshir = 6,
    Paremhat = 7,
    Parmouti = 8,
    Pashons = 9,
    Paoni = 10,
    Epip = 11,
    Mesori = 12,
    PiKogiEnavot = 13
}

public class CopticDate
{
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public CopticMonth Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

I need to implement the following method

```
public static CopticDate ToCopticDate(this DateTime date)
{
    //...        
}
```

Comment: the answer to most complex date/time issues in .NET is usually "Noda Time". I search, and sure enough, it supports the Coptic calendar: https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/userguide/calendars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Marc, I have [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) in my toolbox for jobs like this. You'll need to install the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime).

The implementation is simple - we create a `LocalDate` object from the input date, and convert it to the Coptic calendar using `.WithCalendar(CalendarSystem.Coptic)`. We then return an instance of your class:

```
public static CopticDate ToCopticDate(this DateTime date)
{
    var localDate = LocalDate.FromDateTime(date, CalendarSystem.Gregorian)
                             .WithCalendar(CalendarSystem.Coptic);

    return new CopticDate
    {
        Day = localDate.Day,
        Month = (CopticMonth)localDate.Month,
        Year = localDate.Year
    };
}
```

With an input date of 6 September 2019, I get the following output:

> Day:
> 1
>
> Month:
> PiKogiEnavot
>
> Year:
> 1735

which [so far as I can tell](https://ukmidcopts.org/coptic/calendar) is the expected output.